# Deleting all associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have about 4 models, and let's say they're setup similar to this:

```
first model:
has_many :this

second model:
belongs_to first_model
has_many :these

third_model:
belongs_to second_model
has_many :more_of_these

fourth_model:
belongs_to third_model
```

I would like it to where if someone deletes something that belongs to the second model, then it deletes all of its associations from the third and fourth. Same with the first model (deleting everything associated to model two, three, and four), etc.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for: `dependent: :destroy`

See official documentation here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Deleting+from+associations